# IronSpeed: How to Search all columns in a view

Tags: c#, sql-server, ironspeed

I am using IronSpeed 12.2 for a client, to quickly develop a web app, using .Net 4.5, SQL Server 2008, and C#.

Part of the database structure is a view that uses columns from several tables.

For some reason, the Search panel in IronSpeed only looks at the columns from the first table in the view

This is my view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwActivityDetails]
AS
SELECT a.ID,
       b.BusinessName,
       c.ContactName,
       c.ContactType,
       a.[Description],
       a.Subject,
       a.Author,
       a.[Activity Type],
       a.Notes AS Comments,
       a.[Activity Status] AS Status,
       a.[Effective Date],
       a.[Follow-Up] AS [Follow Up Actions]
FROM tblActivity a
    LEFT JOIN tblBusiness b ON b.BusinessID = a.BusinessID
    LEFT JOIN tblContacts c ON c.ContactID = a.ContactID
```

The Search panel works for all columns as per table alias 'a'.

But it won't search (or report any rows), for data that's in the tables aliased 'b' and 'c'.

Any suggestions, will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Remember filtering `Business` or `Contacts` table columns will convert the `Left join` to `Inner join`

Comment: @Pரதீப் - are you saying the above LEFT joins will be turned into INNER JOINS? In that case I'll create a view to SELECT the previous view, and ISD should only refer to the one "table". Or won't that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face...

Open IronSpeed Designer -> Presentation Layer -> View-Table -> Page Section -> ActionsSearch Panel -> SearchText -> Properties -> Search -> **Search Fields**

In the pop-up box, make sure ALL the columns are included in the Search.

It won't search DateTime columns though. That's another question.